Initializing a local cluster in Dask takes forever
I'm trying out some things with Dask for the first time, and while I had it running a few weeks ago, I now find that I can't get the LocalCluster initiated. I've cut if off after running 30 minutes at some point, and am unable to get it initiated. Does anybody know what the issue may be? The code I'm trying to run is below, it doesn't get past the LocalCluster line.
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client
from dask.diagnostics import ResourceProfiler
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from globals import * # Custom file with some global variables

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394935/what-is-the-right-way-to-close-a-dask-localcluster
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=int(0.9 * mp.cpu_count()), processes=True, threads_per_worker=1, memory_limit="2GB")
print(cluster)
client = Client(cluster)
print(client.dashboard_link)


Could you try a reproducer with minimal imports also? There is no reason a LocalCluster never initiates, except bad environment or imports.

@GuillaumeEB does that mean a fresh environment with only the import necessary to run the LocalCluster line?

@GuillaumeEB I created a fresh environment with only numpy, pandas, scikit-learn and dask and dask-ml, and it still won't initialize

I see from another post you are using Windows, it could also come from default enviornment variables or stuff like that added to Windows OS.
